# How to show an .obj file in python/vtk?

Tags: python, vtk

Good evening,

I want to visualize an .obj file in python using vtk library, but when i run the code i get the following error. knowing that the file exist.
Any help will be thankful.

> ERROR: In /build/vtk-NWL3SN/vtk-5.10.1+dfsg/IO/vtkOBJReader.cxx, line 126
>   vtkOBJReader (0xe16650): File /home/nahla/Documents/cat1_un4 not found
>
> ERROR: In /build/vtk-NWL3SN/vtk-5.10.1+dfsg/Filtering/vtkExecutive.cxx, line 756
>   vtkStreamingDemandDrivenPipeline (0xeb2bc0): Algorithm vtkOBJReader(0xe16650) returned failure for request: vtkInformation (0xeac270)
>     Debug: Off
>     Modified Time: 87
>     Reference Count: 1
>     Registered Events: (none)
>     Request: REQUEST_DATA
>     FROM_OUTPUT_PORT: 0
>     ALGORITHM_AFTER_FORWARD: 1
>     FORWARD_DIRECTION: 0

here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import vtk

ColorBackground = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

FirstobjPath = r"/home/nahla/Documents/cat1_un4"

reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader()

reader.SetFileName(FirstobjPath)

reader.Update()


mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()

if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5:

     mapper.SetInput(reader.GetOutput())

else:

     mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

actor = vtk.vtkActor()

actor.SetMapper(mapper)

# Create a rendering window and renderer

ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()

ren.SetBackground(ColorBackground)

renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()

renWin.AddRenderer(ren)

# Create a renderwindowinteractor

iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()

iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)

# Assign actor to the renderer

ren.AddActor(actor)

# Enable user interface interactor

iren.Initialize()

renWin.Render()

iren.Start()
```

Comment: The error _apparently_ happens on the fourth line of your script, in the call  to `vtk.vtkOBJReader()`. Why on Earth do you include the rest of your code which is completely irrelevant to your question? Instead, please include the complete error message _and_ the output of `ls -l /home/nahla/Documents/cat1_un4`.

Comment: @DYZ Hi, i'm new to vtk and i don't know where the problem comes from!,  the output of 'ls -l /home/nahla/Documents/cat1_un4'  is 'ls: cannot access '/home/nahla/Documents/cat1_un4': No such file or directory' . What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out, i forgot to put ".obj" at the end of the file name. It should be:

> "/home/nahla/Documents/cat1_un4.obj"